# How to send location of the device on server when needed

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I am developing a application in which i need current lat and long of the device.
Time frame to get the lat/long will be decided by the server. Server will send notification whenever lat/lang is required to be fetched. When device get notified from 
the server,at the same time device send its location to server.

**Some conditions:**

- I want lat/long even if device don't have gps
- if user doesn't touch or click the notification,then also i want to fetch
  lat/long, i.e. even if  the  device is in sleep mode.
- Also i don't want to run a background service for the whole day as
  it consumes battery of the device.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would definitely suggest using `Google Cloud Messaging` here. This has the benefit that once a device runs your app, you can make it register against `GCM` and you can send them some message that would make them register their coordinates into your database.

This approach would need that you have to implement some server (for instance, a web server with PHP) and make the users communicate with it, so the flow would be:

1. Your server sends a broadcast message to all registered devices telling them they have to register against the `GCM` service.
2. The devices get the message, and you implement the `BroadcastReceiver` to get both latitude and longitude and send it to your remote server, say `http://www.mysuperserver.com/getlonglat.php`, via a `POST` request.
3. Your server takes both parameters and you save them or do whatever you need.

If you want to follow this approach, this are the steps you have to follow:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com. With your Google account, register a new project. This will provide you an API key and a Sender ID.
2. You'll need to make the device register against your project in `GCM`. You can achieve this by importing `Google Play Services` within your project, and once done, do something alike to this:

   ```
   GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
   final String regid = gcm.register("YOUR_SENDER_ID");
   ```
3. At this time, the `GCM` server already knows that this user has registered whithin your project and has given him a `regid`.
4. The next step is informing your own remote server that the user has done so, and save somewhere the `regid` that it has been given, so you can later send them messages. So in the client side, make a `HTTP POST` request against your server sending that `regid` and process it with somethat like this:

   ```
   $regid = $_POST['regid'];

   if (($regId) && ($ipAddr))
     sql_query("INSERT INTO gcm_subscribers(regid) VALUES($regid')");
   ```
5. Once done, you know who have already registered against your database. You can `SELECT` all the users and send them a signal to send you back their coordinates. In the following example, the parameters would be, firstly, an array of registration IDs and secondly the message to send (for instance, `$messageData = "sendMeYourCoords!"`).

   ```
   function sendNotification($registrationIdsArray, $messageData) {
     $apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

     $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" . $apiKey);
     $data = array(
       'data' => $messageData,
       'registration_ids' => $registrationIdsArray
     );

     $ch = curl_init();

     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);

     return $response;
   }
   ```
6. Once in your client, just process that `GCM` message and make another `POST` to another `URL` on your remote server and pass it the `longitude` and `latitude`. To process the messages I'm including a few links below.

And for getting the coordinates without GPS seems there aren't too much solutions, but there are some. This would be an example: [How to get Latitute Longitude value without using GPS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761367/how-to-get-latitute-longitude-value-without-using-gps-in-android)

More about this:

- Reference on [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html)
- [Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging GCM - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139)
- [Google Cloud Messaging using PHP](http://distriqt.com/post/1273)
- [Connection between PHP (server) and Android (client) Using HTTP and JSON](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/)
- [Notificaciones Push Android: Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). Implementación Cliente (Nueva Versión)](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=4126) (spanish)

Comment: your ans is useful but not as exact match of my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did.

1. Fetch and store locations using the Google Play services fused location provider as described here[here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)
2. I would avoid setting up a service instead you should trigger an alarm that requests for last available location. This further saves battery as the app does not go looking for a location vale but uses what other apps might have recently requested. In my opinion the received response is fairly accurate..
   so do something like this

   ```
   public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   // Restart service every 30 seconds
   private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 5;
   private static final long REPEAT_DAILY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
       Log.v("TEST", "Service loaded at start");
       AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

       Intent i = new Intent(context, ServiceStartReceiver.class);
       PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
       service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

   }
   }
   ```
3. Since you have not mentioned that you want the updates in real time i think you can just dump all data in a temp sqlite database.
4. Create a receiver to listen for changes in network and when over wifi simply send all data to your server. You can be a bit more smart while doing this by sending only when certain number of entries have accumulated or at a periodic interval.
5. Alternatively the server can send a ping to the app via a GCM mnotification which can also trigger sending of data to your server.[this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) is an amazing tutorial to describe sending GCM messages to the app.
6. Finally some very interesting location strategies are mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html). You can pic when to trigger your location save based on user activity or some other context.

Hope this helps.