# how to remove notification fired after application data is cleared from mobile

Tags: java, android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am new to android i would like to know how to disable receiving notification after  application is uninstalled, whether any event or something to detect that app is uninstalled ??? 
i have tried this but not working for me

```
 if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context,BootReceiver.class);
    Identifier = i.getStringExtra("Recognition_flag");
    serverUrl = Constants.urlAll + "uninstall.php";
    LongOperation serverRequest = new LongOperation();
    // serverRequest.execute(serverUrl, user, pass,
    // deviceIMEI);
    serverRequest.execute(serverUrl, user);
    GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
    Log.e(" BroadcastReceiver ", "onReceive called " + " PACKAGE_REMOVED ");
    Toast.makeText(context, " onReceive !!!! PACKAGE_REMOVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 // when package installed
 else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
     Log.e(" BroadcastReceiver ", "onReceive called " + "PACKAGE_ADDED");
     Toast.makeText(context, " onReceive !!!!." + "PACKAGE_ADDED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You want to track when the app is unistalled? Sadly that doesnt happen...
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED is recieved by all other apps present in the mobile expect yours

Comment: @therealprashant thank you. can u plzz tell me how whatsapp and other messaging app stop sending notification to users who unistalled app ?

Comment: Dont know about Whatsapp..thats an entirely different stack...but about others..they use GCM...and before sending notifs..GCM does check that if the user has its device token for that particular app or not...if not then GCM doesnt sends notifs...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994409/how-does-gcm-work-google-cloud-messaging-for-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot detect app uninstalls on Android in any easy way. The broadcast
**android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED** is sent to all the app present in the mobile **but** yours once the app is removed.

Sure there are ways my company has tracked when the app is uninstalled but thats something very tricky and deep.

Comment: thank you for your valuable comment. @therealprashant