# How to download Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement push notifications using GCM. The problem is that it is not showing up in sdk manager(see the screenshot below).

[image]

So how do I go about downloading it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503106/how-to-send-location-of-the-device-on-server-when-needed/22566314#22566314

Answer (score 0):

The image posted by you is not visible, it seems the image is broken.
Anyways, the complete guide to GCM push notification can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Steps are described properly [here](https://developers.geoloqi.com/android/push-notifications).

Hope it helps you.