# Send the latitude and longitude of my mobile device to a local server

Tags: reactjs, server, geolocation, native, expo

I'm working on a project directly on Expo and for the moment what I do is take the coordinates from my cell phone and graph an icon on a map in my current position. So what I need is to send the position of my cell phone to a server that I have on my computer. That is to the localhost of my desktop computer. My computer is connected through the network cable and my cell phone is connected to my home's Wi-Fi network.

Comment: You have been pretty vague about what os platform your phone uses as well as anything you have attempted. If you want some inspiration, maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503106/how-to-send-location-of-the-device-on-server-when-needed

Comment: Send your location to your server via server communication.

Comment: @hongdevelop That's just what I don't know how to do.